# Firebase, update property to the same list

Tags: java, android, firebase

how can I add new reports without adding a new property every single time? Whenever I am trying to update it, I get a new id of the property but I already have it and want to use the same one. So I would like to have another list of crime_type, date, district and etc. I am using Anroding Studio with Java.

```
 {
          "Users": {
            "8Xjf20rH3ZZIFfQHqshfDM0WSYQ2": {
              "age": "27",
              "city": "Manchester",
              "district": "Uni",
              "email": "mail@gmail.com",
              "first_name": "Name",
              "last_name": "NA",
              "post_code": "KG9 203",
              "street_name": "Kings Road",
              "street_number": "543"
            },
            "SJB2yD1c1JSliQaQET1i2w65bhg2": {
              "Reports": [
                {
                  "crime_type": "NA",
                  "date": "12",
                  "district": "TRQ",
                  "reference_number": "123"
                }
              ],
              "age": "21",
              "city": "London",
              "district": "Arsenal",
              "email": "mail@gmail.com",
              "first_name": "Joe",
              "last_name": "Orange",
              "post_code": "BS12 0BW",
              "street_name": "Cesar Road",
              "street_number": "332"
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: "Whenever I am trying to update it, I get a new id of the property" Please edit your question to show the code that isn't working for you. I also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there gives you the best chance that someone can help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.